# Validate the column separator from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I want to know if there's a way to validate the column separator for a CSV file, I'm using the `CsvMapper` library and I know that I can set the column separator using the `.withColumnSeparator()`. I have a CSV file and I want to validate that the file is using the right separator, I use as a separator the '|' character but sometimes the file can have a ';' separator or another one, but I want to validate that the separator is the '|' character.

E.g I have this CSV file with these two lines:

```
A|B|3|e
w|ew|34|w
```

This is a valid file because has as a separator the '|' char.

But sometimes I can received a CSV file like this:

```
A;B;3;e
w;ew;34;w
```

Which is a file separated by ';' Char and does not a '|', that's why I need to validate the column separator

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In a CSV file, the separator is a comma. I suppose there's no hope of getting people to stop referring to all delimited files as Comma Separated Values files, though.

Comment: Not sure about the capabilities of the library, but if there is no support there, I think you will have to do some counting. For the first 100 lines, if there's a fixed number of any of your candidate separators per row, you have found it. Add some wiggle room if needed.